# What do I need to know re. Javascript frameworks?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I recently asked [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733505/what-js-frameworks-play-nice-with-symfony2), which quickly became downvoted and closed. Clearly I lack a deeper understanding of JS, which I'm hoping you'll help me fill here.

I'm a perfectly capable web developer and have built plenty of visually and functionally pleasing websites but am struggling to get to grips with how I should be handling JS.

Up until now, I've only really used jQuery for form validation or providing AJAX functionality to forms/other page elements.

There seems to be a lot of hype around JS frameworks - backbonejs, emberjs, etc, but when I look into them, it looks like they're just good for if you intend to build full applications in them. I'm happy using PHP/Symfony and just want to use JS to give my web applications a nice interactive/responsive 'feel'.

Are the aforementioned frameworks any use to me, or am I right in just sticking with jQuery?

Comment: `Clearly I lack a deeper understanding of JS` appears true as does your misunderstanding about SE sites.  Your question is really too broad for the community to be able to reasonably answer.

Comment: @GlenH7 - So witty...

Comment: stick to jquery.

Comment: I think questions get closed a bit aggressively here, but I do wish people would realize that this is NOT a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't feel like you're doing stuff with Symphony/jQuery, that wasn't intended to do with those frameworks, stick to them.

If you feel like you have to bend time and space to make them do what you wan't they're probably the wrong tools.

I, for example, build GUIs for reporting tools (creating, editing, viewing) so I stick to ExtJS. But I wouldn't build a Company website with it.